# How to debug Psych::SyntaxError during capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

My db push stopped working.

This is my `deploy.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/a20d10a8a25c64c2d238

I am using `'capistrano-db-tasks'`. How to debug where is the problem?

```
Are you sure you want to erase your local database with server database (y)es, (n)o  ? y
local {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"app-development", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>3306}
  * executing "cat /home/app/current/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["213.238.59.107"]
    [213.238.59.107] executing command
    command finished in 345ms
/Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-db-tasks-0.2/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/database.rb:64:in `initialize'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-db-tasks-0.2/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/database.rb:122:in `new'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-db-tasks-0.2/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/database.rb:122:in `remote_to_local'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-db-tasks-0.2/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/dbtasks.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-db-tasks-0.2/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/dbtasks.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/bin/cap:23:in `load'
        from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/gemsets/app/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the `capistrano-db-tasks` Gem that you are using.

Apparently the configuration file that it reads, a YAML file, apparently is malformed.

Psych is the YAML parser shipped with Ruby (https://github.com/tenderlove/psych) which is unable to read your file.

This isn't a Capistrano problem per-se.

Probably the file on your server at `/home/app/current/config/database.yml` isn't readable. You might try running that file through YAML Lint (http://yamllint.com/) to check it for errors.

Recently (within the last two years, around the time 1.9 was becoming popular) the Ruby (aka YARV, CRuby, MRI) switched it's YAML parser, from the [Ruby 2.0 YAML page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html):

> #### Syck¶ ↑
>
> Syck was the original for YAML implementation in Ruby’s standard library developed by why the lucky stiff.
>
> If you prefer, you can still use Syck by changing the `YAML::ENGINE` like so:
>
> `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'`
> `# switch back to the default Psych`
> `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'`

I would ensure that you can read that file on the rails console in your (failed) deploy directory, and also contact the vendor of the `capistrano-db-tasks` gem, it's entirely possible that it's failing on some other YAML file.

Comment: unfortunately both local and server database.yml are valid when I am checking them using YAML Lint.

Comment: I suggest you take the issue up with the `capistrano-db-tasks` gem creator, the error is in their package. I've edited my answer to provide more context which might help you find a solution.